# How bad is it to run an entire HTTP action method in separate thread using Task::Run()?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, c++-cli

I'm writing web services in C++/CLI (not my choice) using Microsoft's Web API. A *lot* of functions in Web API are async, but because I'm using C++/CLI, I don't get the async/await support of C# or VB. So the fallback position is to use [ContinueWith()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith.aspx) to schedule a continuation delegate for reading the async task's result safely.

However, because C++/CLI also doesn't support inline anonymous delegates or managed lambdas, every delegate continuation must be written as a separate function somewhere. That quickly turns into spaghetti with the number of async functions in Web API.

So, to avoid the [deadlock issues](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) of `Task<T>::Result`, I've been trying this:

```
[HttpGet, Route( "get/some/dto" )]
Task< SomeDTO ^ > ^ MyActionMethod()
{
  return Task::Run( gcnew Func< SomeDTO ^ >( this, &MyController::MyActionMethod2 ) );
}
SomeDTO ^ MyActionMethod2()
{
  // execute code and use any task->Result calls I need without deadlocking
}
```

Okay, so I know this isn't great, but how bad is it? I don't yet understand enough of the guts of Web API or ASP.NET to comprehend the performance or scaling ramifications this will have.

Also, what other consequences may this have that aren't necessarily related to performance? For example, exceptions get wrapped in an extra AggregateException, which represents additional complexity and work for handling exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

Your memory usage will increase with your application's parallelism. For every concurrent call to `MyActionMethod` you will need a separate thread with its own stack. That will cost you about 1 MB of RAM for each concurrent call. If `MyActionMethod` runs long enough so that 10000 instances run at once, you're looking at 10 GB of RAM. There is also CPU overhead in setting up each thread.

If concurrency is low, dropping async support won't be a problem. In that case, don't bother with `Task::Run`. Just change `MyActionMethod` to return `SomeDTO^` (no `Task` wrapper).

Another potential concern is that lose easy use of cancellation tokens. However, for Web API it's usually fine to just let an exception propagate back to Web API, which ends up cancelling the synchronous call anyway.

Finally, if you were planning on performing any operation within your action method in parallel, you'll still need to use `ContinueWith` to accomplish that. Going non-async by default means you'll always perform one operation at a time. Fortunately, it's often just fine to do so.

Comment: If I don't use `Task::Run` in `MyActionMethod`, I get deadlocks when accessing `Task<T>::Result`, even when I'm only making one request at a time. That's the reason I put it in.

Comment: To avoid deadlocks, don't use `Task<T>::Result` or `Task…` anything. Have `MyActionMethod` make only synchronous calls (which don't return `Task`-wrapped types). After making the calls, `MyActionMethod` then returns a plain `SomeDTO^`.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Yes, making all calls synchronous avoids the issue, but it's difficult with Web API, since so many of the functions in the framework are async and return tasks.

Comment: As long as you're running in the context of a synchronous Web API method, using Web API client methods synchronously won't deadlock. For example, you can use code like this: `string s = new HttpClient().GetStringAsync("https://example.com").Result;`

Answer (score 1):

> Okay, so I know this isn't great, but how bad is it?

It's difficult to answer this without load-testing your specific scenario. But you can walk through the known semantics (taken largely [from my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html)).

First, when a request comes in, ASP.NET executes your handler on a thread pool thread within that request context. Your request handler calls `Task.Run`, which takes *another* thread from the thread pool and executes the actual request logic on it. The handler then returns the task returned from `Task.Run`; this releases the original request thread back to the thread pool.

Then, the `Task.Run` delegate will block on any asynchronous parts. So, this pattern has the scaling disadvantages of a regular synchronous handler, plus an extra thread context switch. Also, it uses a thread from the ASP.NET thread pool, which is not necessarily a bad thing, but in some scenarios it may throw off the ASP.NET thread pool heuristics.

> Also, what other consequences may this have that aren't necessarily related to performance? For example, exceptions get wrapped in an extra AggregateException, which represents additional complexity and work for handling exceptions.

Yes, the exceptions from any `.Result` or `Wait()` calls will be wrapped in `AggregateException`. You may be able to avoid this by calling `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` instead.

Another important consideration is that the code executing within the `Task.Run` is executing *without* a request context. So, ambient data like `HttpContext.Current`, current culture, thread principal, etc. are not going to be set correctly. You'll have to capture any important data before calling `Task.Run` and pass it down manually.